# select a set of values as a column without CREATE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to write a query that will return all QUERY_ID values alongside all matching TABLE_ID values, where QUERY_ID is not specified in any table, and I can't create tables, so have to specify it in the query itself:

```
QUERY_ID    TABLE_ID
1           1
2           NULL
3           3
4           4
5           NULL
```

I feel like there ought to be a simple way to do this, but I can't think of it for the life of me.  Any help would be wonderful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select q.QUERY_ID, t.TABLE_ID
from (
    select 1 as QUERY_ID
    union all
    select 2 
    union all
    select 3 
    union all
    select 4 
    union all
    select 5 
) q 
left outer join MyTable t on q.QUERY_ID = t.TABLE_ID
```

Comment: ah, yes--I had an itch about UNION ALL but I wasn't putting it together...  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

one way by using the built in master..spt_values table

```
SELECT number AS QUERY_ID,TABLE_ID
FROM master..spt_values v
LEFT JOIN YourTable y ON  y.QUERY_ID = y.TABLE_ID
WHERE TYPE = 'p'
AND number > 0
AND number <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable)
order by QUERY_ID
```

are you able to create #temp tables...can you do this?

```
create table #temp(QUERY_ID int identity,TABLE_ID varchar(200))

insert #temp(TABLE_ID)
select TABLE_ID
from YourTable

select * from #temp
order by QUERY_ID

drop table #temp
```

or like this

```
select identity(int,1,1) as QUERY_ID,TABLE_ID
into #temp
from YourTable

select * from #temp
order by QUERY_ID
```

On sql server 2005 and up there is the row_number function so maybe a reason to upgrade  :-)

Comment: yes it exists but I believe only has 1024 rows not 2048 like on 2005 and up

Comment: Might have been added with service pack 3 or so but don't remember anymore

Comment: ah, I should have specified that my example was a reduction of what I'm really trying to do--QUERY_ID are 7 digit IDs in a non-ordered, discontinuous list...